# Publish multiple images on hub.docker.com in a single repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

I am new to Docker so and this is giving me a headache. I finish developing a site in Magento linking multiple images using docker-compose.yml.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:7.1
    container_name: web
    restart: always
    user: application
    environment:
    - WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN=local.domain.com
    - WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app/pub
    - PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=EST
    - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
    - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2048M
    - PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=300
    - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=500M
    - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=1024M
    volumes:
    - "./:/app:cached"
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    - "32823:22"
    links:
    - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "52000:3306"
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=magento
    volumes:
    - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - PMA_USER=root
    - PMA_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    links:
    - mysql:db
    depends_on:
    - mysql
volumes:
  db-data:
    external: false
```

Then `docker-compose up -d --build`. I have 3 images and 3 containers running on my local machine.

I want to publish these image on hub.docker.com so anyone can download the image and get all the containers running.

Also is there a way to add a MySQL DB to the image, so anyone can have the same running website like I had on my local?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the only thing you can publish on Docker Hub is Docker images; you can't publish containers, volumes, Docker Compose YAML files, or other artifacts.  Since the YAML file is a fairly straightforward text file it's very common to publish that on GitHub, along with a README file explaining how to use it.

You don't need to push the `phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin` or `mariadb` images because those are standard Docker Hub images, so you only need to push your custom image.  I would highly recommend removing the `volumes:` that mounts your local development tree over the image contents to validate that the image actually has what you expect.

> Is there a way to add mysql DB to the image

No.  The various standard Docker database images are built in a way that it is extremely difficult to build an image containing prepopulated data.  [Wordpress image with mysql data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713858/wordpress-image-with-mysql-data) has some good discussion on the topic, and [MySQL Docker container is not saving data to new image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572453/mysql-docker-container-is-not-saving-data-to-new-image) has some good analysis in the question proper.

Comment: Thanks for the response. @David Maze