# how to save data in docker's container?

Tags: docker

I create container postgres with docker-compose:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    # set shared memory limit when using docker-compose
    shm_size: 128mb
    # or set shared memory limit when deploy via swarm stack
    #volumes:
    #  - type: tmpfs
    #    target: /dev/shm
    #    tmpfs:
    #      size: 134217728 # 128*2^20 bytes = 128Mb
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
```

next connect and change database  in container

after I commit container:

docker commit f3a8955f3df6

tag it:

docker tag f3a8955f3df6 myimage

But after run myimage  I receive  clear database. Why?

i     use                 manual

Comment: You need to `bind mount` a directory from host in the container to store `/var/lib/postgres`. Like `docker run ... -v dir:/var/lib/postgres:rw ...`

Comment: @GillesQuénot this needs to be `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, otherwise it will not be persisted (`data` is a separate volume)

Comment: Internally, the database data is always stored in a volume, and `docker commit` does not persist volumes.  Using `docker commit` at all is pretty much never a best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [postgres Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/16/bookworm/Dockerfile) defines [`/var/lib/postgresql/data` as a volume](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/44ef8b226a40f86cf9df3f9299067db6779a3aa3/16/bookworm/Dockerfile#L189C1-L189C32):

```
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Volumes are [not committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349071/commit-content-of-mounted-volumes-as-well).

Comment: I don't understand. If I set volume, what will change? I need create image with my data and use in future . Can I do it?

Comment: @АндрейДов You need to create a new image which does not define the directory as volume, then copy over the data from the volume. Volumes cannot be committed, you have to do it manually (as explained in the linked answer)

Comment: Alternatively, choose a different path for the data directory of the database, which is not a volume mount (as explained in the duplicate).